# Finding Nearest 2 Points

Tags: java, algorithm

I was wodnering if anyone could help me with this: I am trying to create a piece of Java code that finds the 2 nearest points to a point. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  static int distance(int x1, int x2) {
    return Math.round((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
    // Math.sqrt is the square root of the 2 co-ordinates
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int x2, x1; // The Points
    int distance;// The Math to work out distance
    int randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10) + 1;// For Length of array
    int[] distances = new int[randomInt2];// The Array
    int store;

    x1 = 0;// used to calculate distance from original point to current point
    System.out.println("Distance Generated for Point 1 : 0");// For First Point

    int origin = 1;// increment which point start from
    int range = 0;// Amount of Points
    int point = 2;// Counts the number of points
    while (range < randomInt2) {
      int randomInt3 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10) + 2;// Distance for all points besides first
      x2 = randomInt3;
      distance = distance(x1, x2); // System.out.println("The distance between point 1 and point " +point+ " is " + distance + " .");
      System.out.println("Distance from Point " + origin + " to Point " + point + " is distance = " + distance);
      store = distance;// stores the distance to be put into array
      point++;// increments the point number each time
      distances[range] = store;
      // System.out.println(" ,from Point " +point+" to Point "+origin+" = " + distance);
      origin++;// Increments Original Point
      range++;// increments amount of points each time
    }
    /*
     * for (int val : distances) { System.out.println(val); }
     */
  }
}
```

So far it creates points with random distances and I am able to find the nearest point for each point from the previous. However I am trying to make it so that I can make a sort of tree structure where each point has 2 of the closest points to that branching off it. Sorry if im not making this clear however if anyone can give me any tips they will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to rewrite your code such that: You use a `class Point` which contains `x1` and `x2`; You provide an array of points `Point [] points` which represent the list of all your points; You provide an empty method such this: `Point [] findTwoNearestPoints(Point [] listOfPoints, Point point)`. With the current code I cannot understand anything of what you're trying to do, sorry.

Comment: It seems that you are comparing 1-dimensional points. An advise is to look at your `distance` function. There is no need to square the distance, use `Math.abs` to get the distance between `x1` and `x2`. Math.round is unnecessary as you are trying to round an integer value.

Comment: Terrible variable names, no proper indentation and you really need some refactoring to make the code readable. As it is, it is difficult to determine what you are actually doing there...

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to guess what you want to do. From how I read your question you want to create some points on a line (i.e. one-dimensional points) and find for each of those points the two closest other points.

---------A-----------B---------C-D-E-----------

For these points A-E on the line this should result in something like:
A's neighbors are B and C.
B's neighbors are A and C.
C's neighbors are D and E.
D's neighbors are C and E.
E's neighbors are C and D.

However your code has results like:
A has distance d to B.
B has distance d to C.
C has distance d to D.
D has distance d to E.

There are already a few suggestions on how to improve your code, I will add those now and name a few others.

### What is your exact problem?

We can only guess at the moment, since your code does something completely different from what your question reads. Think about it again and try to give some clearer questions.

### Try to think object-oriented

Already mentioned: It's better to have some classes, at least e.g. a class for the `Point`s. Also it might be good to put the `distance` method into another Class, maybe some kind of a math library.
Also think about visibility. Package visibility (what your `distance()` method uses) is usually not what you have in mind.
Using classes makes your code more structured and often easier to extend or adds some reusabilty.

### Variable names and code style

We can hardly guess what you mean by `range`, `randomInt2` and `store`. If you have a proper context, a good indentation and some meaningful names, we can easier guess what it does, even with less comments.

Another problem you have is that you reuse x2 again and again. Eventually you have some distances, stored in your distance-array, but no idea to which point they belong - since those points don't exist anymore.

### Resolving the problem

Okay, although your question is not the most helpful one, I will try to solve the problem.

First think of a Point class. I decided to call it `Point1D`, to show that it can easily be extended to a `Point2D` later, or `Point3D`.

```
package sto;

public class Point1D {
    private final double x; // this could also be a good public variable
    private final String name;

    public Point1D(double x, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point1D other) {
        return Math.abs(other.x - this.x);
    }
}
```

This could be a simple `Point1D` class for your needs. It holds a `String name`, the value (here `double x`) and also a method to calculate the distance between this `Point1D` and another one: `public double distanceTo(Point1D other)`.

In your `Main` you can now create a random amount of points which are reusable quite easy:

```
package sto;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();

        // generate points
        int numberOfPoints = rng.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Point1D[] points = new Point1D[numberOfPoints];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            points[i] = new Point1D(rng.nextDouble() * 10.0d, "Point " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This will create 1-10 points in the `Point1D[] points` array. Note the naming: `numberOfPoints` is more meaningful than `randomInt2`.

Since you have a distance function int the main, we can also add this. Note that we do this with public visibility now, so that it is accessible from everywhere:

```
    public static double distance(Point1D p1, Point1D p2) {
        return p1.distanceTo(p2);
    }
```

It would even be better to move methods like this to a seperate class, something like `MathUtil`. And since I already created `distanceTo(Point1D)` it's not needed at the moment anyway.

Now you want to find the two closest points for each point. There are probably much better ways than this one to do it, but this one does it well:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            Point1D currentPoint = points[i];

            Point1D closestPoint = null;
            Point1D secondClosestPoint = null;
            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPoints; ++j) {
                if(i == j) continue;
                if(closestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(closestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = closestPoint;
                    closestPoint = points[j];
                } else if(secondClosestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(secondClosestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = points[j];
                }
            }
            currentPoint.setNeighbors(closestPoint, secondClosestPoint);
        }
```

First we define the closest and second closest points and initialize them with null. Then we compare the distances between the current point and the other points, whenever the distance is closer than the current closest point, we assign it. Otherwise we check for the second closest point. Note the `null` checks, this is to avoid null-pointer exceptions and (in case you say: hey, I can just initialize it with `points[0]` or `points[j]` all the time) that you compare the distances with zero distance (in case `currentPoint` equals `points[0]` or `currentPoint` equals `points[j]`) or you set closest and second closest initially to the closest point.

Note also that with only 1 or 2 generated points one or both neighbors will be `null`.

The last method call `currentPoint.setNeighbors(closestPoint, secondClosestPoint);` is new to you. Somehow you want to store the neighbors. Instead of real tree structure (which you should be able to build with what you have after this answer) I just decided to store the neighbors in the `Point1D` objects themselves. For this the `Point1D` class was altered a little bit:

```
    /* extensions for your special case: two neighbors */
    private Point1D neighbor1 = null;
    private Point1D neighbor2 = null;

    public void setNeighbors(Point1D p1, Point1D p2) {
        neighbor1 = p1;
        neighbor2 = p2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Point1D \"" + name + "\" at " + x + ", "
             + "Neighbors: " + (neighbor1 != null? neighbor1.name + " (" + distanceTo(neighbor1) + "), " : "") 
                             + (neighbor2 != null? neighbor2.name + " (" + distanceTo(neighbor2) + ")" : ""); 
    }
```

The Point1D gets two simple members and a setter for those. Of course you can modify this easily, and also extend it with getters and so on. I also overloaded `public String toString()` to be able to print the `Point1D`s easily.

After all we just need to print them, which is just another very simple for loop.

### Complete code

Main.java

```
package sto;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    // better into a seperate MathLibrary
    public static double distance(Point1D p1, Point1D p2) {
        return p1.distanceTo(p2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();

        // generate points
        int numberOfPoints = rng.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Point1D[] points = new Point1D[numberOfPoints];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            points[i] = new Point1D(rng.nextDouble() * 10.0d, "Point " + i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            Point1D currentPoint = points[i];

            Point1D closestPoint = null;
            Point1D secondClosestPoint = null;
            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPoints; ++j) {
                if(i == j) continue;
                if(closestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(closestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = closestPoint;
                    closestPoint = points[j];
                } else if(secondClosestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(secondClosestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = points[j];
                }
            }
            currentPoint.setNeighbors(closestPoint, secondClosestPoint);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i)
            System.out.println(points[i]);
    }
}
```

Point1D.java

```
package sto;

public class Point1D {
    private final double x; // this could also be a good public variable
    private final String name;

    public Point1D(double x, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point1D other) {
        return Math.abs(other.x - this.x);
    }

    /* extensions for your special things: 2 neighbors */
    private Point1D neighbor1 = null;
    private Point1D neighbor2 = null;

    public String toString() {
        return "Point1D \"" + name + "\" at " + x + ", "
             + "Neighbors: " + (neighbor1 != null? neighbor1.name + " (" + distanceTo(neighbor1) + "), " : "") 
                             + (neighbor2 != null? neighbor2.name + " (" + distanceTo(neighbor2) + ")" : ""); 
    }

    public void setNeighbors(Point1D p1, Point1D p2) {
        neighbor1 = p1;
        neighbor2 = p2;
    }

}
```

### Example outputs

With 1 generated Point:

```
Point1D "Point 0" at 6.420136069230588, Neighbors:
```

With 2 generated Points:

```
Point1D "Point 0" at 5.944088209230237, Neighbors: Point 1 (0.43915003704614364), 
Point1D "Point 1" at 6.383238246276381, Neighbors: Point 0 (0.43915003704614364),
```

With more than 2 points:

```
Point1D "Point 0" at 8.843803983191671, Neighbors: Point 8 (1.1272536955360408), Point 3 (1.561097922588882)
Point1D "Point 1" at 5.769064395124087, Neighbors: Point 9 (0.2901718634798556), Point 3 (1.5136416654787022)
Point1D "Point 2" at 3.1745401994446834, Neighbors: Point 7 (0.23098459949774464), Point 5 (0.2711748146393602)
Point1D "Point 3" at 7.28270606060279, Neighbors: Point 9 (1.2234698019988466), Point 1 (1.5136416654787022)
Point1D "Point 4" at 1.3174388168729179, Neighbors: Point 5 (1.5859265679324053), Point 7 (1.6261167830740209)
Point1D "Point 5" at 2.903365384805323, Neighbors: Point 7 (0.04019021514161558), Point 2 (0.2711748146393602)
Point1D "Point 6" at 3.8143932773804448, Neighbors: Point 2 (0.6398530779357614), Point 7 (0.870837677433506)
Point1D "Point 7" at 2.9435555999469387, Neighbors: Point 5 (0.04019021514161558), Point 2 (0.23098459949774464)
Point1D "Point 8" at 9.971057678727712, Neighbors: Point 0 (1.1272536955360408), Point 3 (2.6883516181249227)
Point1D "Point 9" at 6.059236258603943, Neighbors: Point 1 (0.2901718634798556), Point 3 (1.2234698019988466)
```

### Exercise

Try to implement this for a Point2D and a Point3D, use a `public static double distance(PointND p1, PointND p2)` in a seperate `MathUtil.java`.

Comment: Hey sorry took so long to reply but thank you very much for your help it has really helped me to understand what im doing and where i have been going wrong and sorry i have not been very clear,originally i was trying to find the nearest neighbours using K-NN, Insetead of using the brute force algorithm where is shows all points from all distances i wanted to only show 2 of the closest points to that point which is what you have managed to do, this guide has really helped me so i thank you greatly!

Comment: use a max heap and time complexity would be nlogp, n - total number of points and p is the number of closest point you want to find out